# React JS Switch Router with admin only pages not hitting my 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to restrict parts of my app to logged in users only. 
I have this working using the code below.

However, previously I was making use of the **Switch** router to send users to a 404 page when no matching routes are found.

For some reason since I adding the **EnsureLoggedIn** component to **App.jsx** the user is never redirected to the 404 page.

Test: Random path entered in URL. Should route to the 404 page.

- **isLoggedIn=false** : The user gets directed to the /login page.
- **isLoggedIn=true** : No matching route is found and the page container is rendered empty.

I'd expect the switch router to ignore what's nested inside **EnsureLoggedIn** since none of the routes match, then render the 404.

Hoping someone with a bit more React experience can steer me on this.

**App.jsx**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header/>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
   <Route exact path="/someotherpage" component={SomeOtherPage}/>
   <EnsureLoggedIn>
     <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
   </EnsureLoggedIn>
   <Route component={Error404Page}/>
  </Switch>
  <Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**EnsureLoggedIn.jsx**

```
 class EnsureLoggedIn extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
   }

   render() {
     const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
     if (isLoggedIn) {
       return this.props.children
     } else {
        return ( <Redirect to="/login" /> );
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Switch>` renders the first matching child `<Route>` - however your `<EnsureLoggedIn>` component gets rendered anyway and circumvents the `<Switch>` exclusivity by explicitly rendering its children. I'm not sure this kind of hierarchy is supported.

Consider having a `<LoggedInEnsuringDashboard>` or similar and putting that straight into the `Router` without the nesting.

Edit:

Something along the lines of:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header/>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
   <Route exact path="/someotherpage" component={SomeOtherPage}/>
   <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={LoggedInEnsuringDashboard}/>
   <Route component={Error404Page}/>
  </Switch>
  <Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And

```
class LoggedInEnsuringDashboard extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   render() {
     if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
       return <Dashboard>
     } else {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also found that react-router v4 doesn't like nested routes. I'd based my approach on an out of date tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another approach which I ended up using.

This involves creating a container called UserArea which has all the admin only pages listed as subcontainers.

Then in the render function, the following ensures that any url which begins with /user-area will be redirected to the login page if the user is not logged in.

```
this.isLoggedIn() ? (<UserArea />) : (<Redirect to="/login" />) )
```

**App.jsx**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header/>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
   <Route exact path="/someotherpage" component={SomeOtherPage}/>
   <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
   <Route path="/user-area" render={ ()=>(this.isLoggedIn() ? (<UserArea />) : (<Redirect to="/login" />) )} />
   <Route component={Error404Page}/>
  </Switch>
  <Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**UserArea.jsx**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <main className="ks-main-content ks-container__user-area">
    <UserAreaHeader />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/user-area/dashboard" component={UserAreaDashboardPage}/>
      <Route exact path="/user-area/profile" component={UserAreaProfile}/>
      <Route component={Error404Page} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
</BrowserRouter>
```